# How to store one record into an existing array with AsyncStorage React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an existing array myItems and the list of items, fetched from API (array itemsFromApi) and rendered as a Flatlist. **I want to store each item (not an array of items) into an existing array and save it local.**

What i tried to do:

1. Fetch array of items from api and render it as an Flatlist.
2. Save each item to an existing array myItems (using useState)
3. Use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to store an array myItems as a value via AsyncStorage

What i have:

1. Fetch items and storing it into array myItems works good.
2. In AsyncStorage is stored only one item, although i store an array
   using AsyncStorage.
3. After re-render an array myItems is empty, AsyncStorage has only one item.

Here is peace of code:

```
// Array myItems, where i'd like to store the data
const [myItems, setMyItems] = useState([]); 

// Array of data from api
const [itemsFromApi, setItemsFromApi] = useState([]); 

// Fetch items from API and render it as a Flatlist, works good
const getItems = async () => {
   const response = await api.get('/...');
   setItemsFromApi(response.data)
};

<FlatList 
    data={itemsFromApi}
    keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index.toString() }
    renderItem={({ item })=>{
           return (
             <TouchableOpacity>
                 <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                 <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                 <Button title="Add" onPress={()=>{addItem(item))} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
       )
   }}
 />

// Save fetched items to array myItems
const addItem = (item) => {
   setMyItems([...myItems, item]);
   storeData();
};


// trying to store array myItems using AsyncStorage
 const storeData = async (myItems) => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('STORAGE_KEY', JSON.stringify(myItems));
          Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
        }
      };

// trying to retrieve data 
const retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('STORAGE_KEY');
      if (value !== null) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(value))
        }
      } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
      }
        return null;
  };
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong, but I don’t understand what.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: wherea re you calling storeData?

Comment: In `addItem()` right after  `setMyItems([...myItems, item]);` (it was a typo in code, but it still doesn't work). So the function, that i call to add and store the item is `setMyItems([...myItems, item]); storeData();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It was:

```
const addItem = (item) => {
   setMyItems([...myItems, item]);
   storeData();
};
```

Modified:

```
const addItem = (item) => {
   myItems.push(item); // <- Here is the trick
   storeData();
   setMyContacts([...myItems]);
};
```

1. When i set just `setMyContacts(myItems)`, the list on the screen not be updated.
2. When i set `setMyContacts([...myItems , item])` an item is duplicated in state and be shown at screen twice. Correct is `setMyContacts([...myItems])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below.

```
<FlatList 
    data={itemsFromApi}
    keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index.toString() }
    renderItem={({ item })=>{
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                <Button title="Add" onPress={()=>{setMyItems([...myItems, item]))} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }}
/>
```

Comment: It's exactly what do the function addItem(), it's save items to an array myItems, but not store it local via AsyncStorage. The issue is store the each item to an array locally.